# Excel Formula to search with this criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my data

[image]

How do i calculate the total of all 'w add' that have non-blank 'g minus' value. For example, in the image i would add 5.61 and 160.11 and store it in a single value. i have no idea how to do this with SUMIF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
=SUMIF(D2:D15,"<>",A2:A15)
```

The <> checks if the cells are not blank